# image is not showing in the table

Tags: html, image, symfony, twig

How to show a image in a table !!

I am trying to show an image in a table, but it is coming blank !

This is my html/twig code --

```
<td>
    <div style="background-image: url('{% if content.image_url is defined %}/imagex/{{ content.image_url }}{% endif %}')"></div>
</td>
```

here `{{ content.image_url }}` contains the image.

the output look like so ---

```
<tr class="">
<td><div style="background-image: url('/imagex/product-image-1-url')"></div></td>vb 
 </tr>
 <tr class="">
 <td><div style="background-image: url('/imagex/https://hello.com/6c26a/original.png')"></div></td>vb 
</tr>
```

i have also tried like so ---

```
{% if content.image.url is defined %}/imagex/{{ content.image.base64url }}
```

But no luck !!!

Any one knows how to fix this issue !!

Comment: Can you include the source/output of the above code in your post? It may give a clue if we can see what you actually get.

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="//your link//"><img src="//image url//"></a>
        </td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```